# clusterdb stopped working for PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: postgresql, security, linux, ubuntu, postgresql-9.2

After a fresh PostgreSQL install (version 9.2) on my Ubuntu server 12.04, clusterdb utility stopped working. I used the same config files as I used with version 9.1.

Below is the actual command:

```
clusterdb -v -h localhost -p <port#> -U postgres -d <dbname>
```

And this is the response that I'm getting:

```
clusterdb: could not connect to database <dbname>: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port <port#>?
```

I'm able to connect to the server locally and from outside. I can also use another utilities  such as **pg_dump** with no problems.

My pg_hba.conf file below:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local all postgres peer
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host all all ::1/128 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
local all postgres md5
host all all x.x.x.x/x md5         #my network
host    all all  x.x.x.x/x  md5    #internal ip of the server
```

Are there any security changes were implemented in PostgreSQL 9.2 vs 9.1 that may prevent **clusterdb** to work properly?

Comment: See what `pg_lsclusters` says, and `netstat -tln` for the addresses and ports that are listened to.

Comment: @DanielVérité: netstat -tln showed that postgres was listening on that ipdess/port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something went wrong when you upgraded. You have to check that the `port` and `listen_addresses` are correct. Perhaps the `listen_address` changed and the instance isn't listening on the host anymore?

The reason that `pg_dump` and the other tools are still working is probably because they're connecting over the unix socket instead over TCP/IP. `clusterdb` should also be able to do that if you just leave out the `-h` and `-p` options.

The `pg_hba.conf` is not relevant because your client can't connect to the server at all. You can verify that the server is listening on the expected host and port with `telnet <host> <port>`.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: Thank you! removing 'h' and 'p' did help with this issue. I also had to edit pg_hba.conf file and change `local all postgres peer` to `local all postgres md5`